# Intellij Idea\ AndroidStudio prefix of created variables

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

When i want to create a **new variable** using incoming passed parameters(`Alt + Enter` key combination) by default i create a variable that called like a passed parameter.

For example :

> public MyObject(int capacity)

When i press `Alt + Enter` IDE was displayed a dialog where i can choose the future variable name.

**By default variable calls like a incoming parameter. - `capacity`**

I want to add to all variables which will be created in the future prefix `m` automatically to get a next result :

> int mCapacity

instead of

> int capacity

How i can do that? And is that possible?

Comment: When/Where exactly do you press Alt + Enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the "Create field for parameter 'X'" alt+Enter item, you can accomplish this by

1. Going to `Preferences > Code Style > Java`
2. Under the "Code GenerationO tab, there is an area called "naming".
3. Put an `m` in the "Field" row, "Name Prefix" column.

[image]